# How to tail multiple gz files

Tags: command-line, bash, tail

To tail multiple log files, I use:

```
tail /path/to/logs/*.log
```

To tail a zipped log file:

```
zcat /path/to/mylog.1.gz | tail
```

But I'd like to tail multiple zipped log files since the output of the following will not be readable:

```
tail /path/to/logs/*.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

With reading `zcat`'s output for each single filename(*No globbing*) from a named pipe using `bash`'s process substitution syntax ... e.g. like so:

```bash
tail <(zcat /path/to/mylog.1.gz) <(zcat /path/to/mylog.2.gz) ...
```

or with shell's filename globbing using a `for` loop ... e.g. like so:

```bash
for f in /path/to/logs/*.gz; do echo "====> $f"; zcat "$f" | tail; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

`ls -1 /path/to/logs/*.log.gz | xargs -i bash -c "zgrep -H . {}   | tail -2 "`

Comment: I'd suggest something more like `printf '%s\0' /var/log/*.gz | xargs -r0 -I {} sh -c 'zgrep -H . "$1" | tail -n 2' sh {}` or (borrowing [Raffa's idea](https://askubuntu.com/a/1451911/178692) to make a `tail`-like multi-file header) `printf '%s\0' /var/log/*.gz | xargs -r0 -I {} sh -c 'printf "====> %s\n" "$1"; zcat "$1" | tail -n 2' sh {}`